# Aplicação Crasheando em tempo de execução

Tags: swift

Eu criei três aplicações em Swift, elas estavam funcionando normalmente, mas de um tempo para cá elas pararam e não consigo identificar o erro. Já pesquisei muito e não consigo resolver.
Elas funcionam no emulador, mas quando tento instalar no Iphone, elas quebram e geram o log abaixo:

Alguém pode me ajudar?!

Abraços.

```
Incident Identifier: 43291A73-37F3-404A-9BF4-ED2172C3EA6A
CrashReporter Key:   94379fae224c5080d8d8b86dd97daf1c4330192b
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             Alimentar [370]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/266AC723-76C1-4F53-A03D-AB3BF8C244EE/Alimentar.app/Alimentar
Identifier:          com.prevencao.Alimentar
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-03-24 10:11:21.21 -0300
Launch Time:         2016-03-24 10:11:21.21 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 9.3 (13E233)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/266AC723-76C1-4F53-A03D-AB3BF8C244EE/Alimentar.app/Alimentar
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/266AC723-76C1-4F53-A03D-AB3BF8C244EE/Alimentar.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/266AC723-76C1-4F53-A03D-AB3BF8C244EE/Alimentar.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
  Dyld Version: 390.7

Binary Images:
0x9d000 - 0xc0fff Alimentar armv7  <fd5d8051614e3f918feec46e0e661023> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/266AC723-76C1-4F53-A03D-AB3BF8C244EE/Alimentar.app/Alimentar
0x1fe20000 - 0x1fe47fff dyld armv7s  <d96d5b718d2b3c3bad7f17d4e8a3f049> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Parece que é algo referente a avfoundation. Tenta fazer um clean e depois rebuild o App. Favor postar o código que gera o erro/crash e a linha que acontece. Tenta adicionar break points no seu código para identificar ate aonde o seu código ta sendo executado. Tenta isolar o problema criando um novo projeto.

Comment: Leo Dabus muito obrigado pela ajuda, já tentei fazer a Clean, mas não adiantou o problema persiste.
Vou tentar fazer o debug, como você falou, mas não sou experiente em programação, talvez eu precise de ajuda para debugar. Você me auxilia?

Comment: Como eu ja disse o melhor e criar um projeto novo e a testa o codigo que voce acha wue esteja dando o problema separado do resto. Na maioria da vezes em que eu nao consegui identificar o problema recriar o projeto sempre resolveu.

Comment: Valeu Leo Dabus.Vou fazer isso.